# Вызов функции из обновленного файла на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть скрипт на питоне, который работает круглые сутки.
Раз в какое-то время он выполняет задание по крону и в остальное время ждет комманды из пользователя.

Если пришла команда от пользователя скрипт выполняет определенно действие.

Я хочу разбить это на два файла, так чтобы то что работает круглые сутки работало, а когда приходила команда - пересылала ее во второй файл а тот уже возвращал ответ.

Казалось бы, можно сделать import и вопрос закрыт. Но, я бы хотел в процессе разработки второй файл постоянно изменять и тестировать снова без перезапуска основного скрипта.

То есть задача каждый раз делать import и чтобы файл перекомпилировался. Собственно вопрос: как?

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/437589/2110496